# How do i set up stylus with Webstorm on a windows machine?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, stylus

I went through all the steps (the i saw on webstorm) to install stylus through node on windwos, but i'm getting:

An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Stylus'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\bin\stylus" (in directory "C:\dev\patch\src\main\resources\web\home\css"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Make sure C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylus\bin\stylus.bat is existant otherwise perform a file search and located its correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Install stylus globally

```
npm install stylus --global
```

Now you can find the stylus.cmd on C directory, for me the file was located at:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\stylus.cmd
```

Now you have `stylus.cmd` in PATH so you can introduce in WebStorm only file name without its' path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `stylus` script you are specifying is a node app itself and you can't execute it on Windows (as it's just a file with JavaScript code inside, not a batch or an executable). You should look for the `stylus.bat` file instead (which may be in the completely different directory). With my node installation it appears as `c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\stylus.cmd`.

If you can't find it there, use the whole drive search for the `stylus.cmd` and specify the full path to this file in the File Watcher **Program** field.